# Uninstall Vista update without being able to run Windows

Tags: windows-vista, update, uninstall

The PC of a friend will no longer boot into Windows (not even safe mode). I have recovered the crash dump file and run it through WinDbg. This indicates that the problem comes from WinInit.exe and the error is VISTA DRIVER FAULT

Also in my investigations I have found that 8 Windows upgrades were downloaded and installed the last time the PC booted OK, 5 of which were security updates. As the next step, I want to uninstall these updates but as I cannot boot into Windows I can't do it in the normal way.

I have tried using the restore points on the system, but there are non stored.

Is there any way I can revert or delete these updates only the drive in a seperate PC ?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

At this point it may well be quicker to do a repair install. Note you need a Vista DVD at the same or later service pack level to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tools in DaRT (Diagnostic and Recovery Toolset), a part of Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack.

Comment: The Hotfix Uninstall shows only 1 of the 8 hotfixes that were in the WindowsUpdate.log file. When I try to uninstall that one I get 'Failed. Error: Indicates two revision levels are incompatible'